# Instagram like indicator animation behaviour in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

I have created Instagram like stories in Jetpack Compose and added auto-scroll functionality which works fine but, if I am on 3rd page and the previous two indicators are in filled state and 3rd indicator starts animating now if I swipe the page to the previous page I want to stop the next page animation and start the animation of current page
how can I achieve this?

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun Stories(data: List<Int>) {
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(
        initialPage = 0,
        initialPageOffsetFraction = 0f
    )
    var currentPage by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }
    val coScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(16.dp)
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
    ) {
        Story(state = pagerState, data = data)
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(
                    start = 16.dp,
                    top = 16.dp,
                    end = 16.dp
                ),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)
        ) {
            for (index in data.indices) {
                Indicators(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .height(4.dp)
                        .weight(1f),
                    currentPage == index,
                    state = pagerState,
                    index = index,
                ) {
                    coScope.launch {
                        if (currentPage < data.size - 1) {
                            currentPage++
                        }
                        pagerState.animateScrollToPage(currentPage)

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun Story(state: PagerState, data: List<Int>) {
    HorizontalPager(
        modifier = Modifier,
        state = state,
        pageCount = data.size
    ) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier.height(440.dp),
            painter = painterResource(id = data[it]),
            contentDescription = "StoryImage",
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
        )
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun Indicators(
    modifier: Modifier,
    startAnimate: Boolean,
    state: PagerState,
    index: Int,
    onAnimateComplete: () -> Unit
) {
    var progress by remember {
        mutableStateOf(.0f)
    }

    val animateProgress by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = progress,
        animationSpec = ProgressIndicatorDefaults.ProgressAnimationSpec,
        label = ""

    )
    LaunchedEffect(state.currentPage) {
        if (startAnimate) {
            while (progress < 1f) {
                progress += 0.01f
                delay(50)
            }
            onAnimateComplete()

        }
    }


    LinearProgressIndicator(
        modifier = modifier.clip(RoundedCornerShape(12.dp)),
        color = Color.White,
        trackColor = Color.Gray,
        progress = animateProgress
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The Indicators component represents each individual `indicator`. It uses a progress value to control the fill of the `indicator`.
2. `progress` value is calculated based on the current page and offset from the `pagerState`.
3. When you click on an `indicator`, it uses `animateScrollToPage` to smoothly transition to the selected page.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun Stories(data: List<Int>) {
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(
        initialPage = 0,
        initialPageOffsetFraction = 0f
    )
    val coScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(16.dp)
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
    ) {
        Story(state = pagerState, data = data)
        StoryIndicator(data = data, pagerState = pagerState, coScope = coScope)
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun StoryIndicator(data: List<Int>, pagerState: PagerState, coScope: CoroutineScope) {
    val currentPage = pagerState.currentPage
    val pageCount = data.size
    val progress = (currentPage + pagerState.currentPageOffset) / (pageCount - 1)

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(16.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)
    ) {
        for (index in data.indices) {
            Indicators(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(4.dp)
                    .weight(1f),
                isCurrent = index == currentPage,
                progress = if (index == currentPage) progress else if (index < currentPage) 1f else 0f,
                onClick = {
                    coScope.launch {
                        pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index)
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun Indicators(modifier: Modifier, isCurrent: Boolean, progress: Float, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    val color = if (isCurrent) Color.White else Color.Gray

    Box(
        modifier = modifier.clickable { onClick() },
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(4.dp)
                .width(24.dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(percent = 50))
                .background(color)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I want an animation to be played and auto-scrolled enabled and all previous indicator is in the active state until the previous page is selected. Same like Instagram or WhatsApp stories.